# How to find node from node properties but without mentioning label in neo4j using py2neo

Tags: neo4j, py2neo

I am new to neo4j and py2neo. I have simple db where each node is a place eg. airport or railway station.  I have added these as labels. There is also unique place_id as a property for each node. I want to get the node that corresponds some particular place_id but I dont know label.

I can do this if I know label :

```
graph.find_one("airport", "place_id", 413)
```

but I want to do something similar to:

```
graph.find_one("place_id", 413)
```

Also Do I need to create some Index? if yes then how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use cypher to do what you want, but keep in mind that matching a node without specifying a label will fetch every node to check if property matches.

```
graph.cypher.execute("MATCH (place) where place.place_id=413 RETURN place")
```

To create indexes, everything you need is on [py2neo documentation](http://py2neo.org/2.0/) or you can create them [using neo4j web interface](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-schema-index.html)